# Hahn-Banach extensions from $E$ to $E^{**}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

I was thinking the following problem while reading some functional analysis notes.

> Is it possible to characterize the Hahn-Banach extensions (meaning, extensions with the same norm) of a
> functional in a Banach space $E$ to the double continuous dual
> $E^{**}$?

My intuition tells me that there aren't many. This is due to two facts:

> **Theorem 1** (Goldstine) The unit ball $B_E$ of $E$ is $w^*$-dense in the unit ball of $E^{**}$, $B_{E^{**}}$
>
> **Theorem 2** There is a canonical (H-B) extension of a functional $\varphi \in E^*$ given by the natural map $E^* \to E^{***}$. Even more so, this map splits.

Are there examples of spaces and functionals that admit many H-B extensions to its double dual?

Just for reference, the first example one would think is $c_0$ which has $c_0^{**}=\ell^\infty$. But in this case, it is well known that the H-B extension is always unique.

**Edit**: I'll extend the results I know a little in order to attain a possible answer.

> **Theorem 3** (Phelps) Given a closed subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$, every functional on $Y$ has a unique norm-preserving extension if and only if the distance from a functional $f \in X^*$ to $Y^\perp$ is attained uniquely, in the sense that there exists a unique $g \in Y^\perp$ such that
> $$ d(f,Y^\perp) = \|f-g\|$$

Form this is an easy exercise that the Hahn-Banach extension is always unique if and only if the dual space is strictly convex.

Using theorem 3 and theorem 2, it is also possible to observe the following:

> The triple dual, $E^{***}$ splits
> $$ E^{***} = E^* \oplus E^\perp$$
> Then every functional on $E$ admits unique H-B extension to $E^{**}$ if and only if the norm on $E^{***}$ satisfies
> $$\|f\|_{E^{***}} = \|f|_E\|_{E^*} + \| f - f_E \|_{E^\perp} $$

Is this always the case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding your question - how are you extending a point in $E$ to something in $E**$? Is it just the evaluation map?

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes, I'm identifying $E$ with it's image in $E^{**}$ through the evaluation map.

Comment: And given $\varphi \in E^{**}$, it is an extension of $f \in E$ if they have the same norm?

Comment: @B.Mehta I'm using the term "Hahn-Banach" extension to mean that it is an extension with the same norm, as is written on the question.

Comment: Yes, but I'm unclear how you're defining extension.

Comment: @B.Mehta Given any functional $\phi:E \to \mathbb{C}$, it is possible to extend it to $\tilde{\phi}:E^{**} \to \mathbb{C}$ through the Hahn-Banach theorem. What I'm asking is, "How many possible  extensions are that have the same norm?" and "Which functionals on $E^{**}$ come from extensions of functionals of the same norm on $E$?"

Comment: Ah! I see, I thought we were extending points **in** $E$ but you're asking about functionals **on** $E$. My mistake.

Comment: When $E=E^{**}$, I know of the following partial characterisation: the extension is unique if and only if the unit ball of $E^*$ is strictly convex. I'm not sure what happens when $E$ is not reflexive, however...

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist if $E=E^{**}$ (that is, $E$ is reflexive) then every functional on $E$ is the same as a functional on $E^{**}$, no extension is necessary. I'm aware of the fact that every continous functional on a **subspace** of $E$ extends uniquely (with norm preservation) if and only if $E^*$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your post. I was thinking of subspaces of $E$. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to come back to this question but I've found an answer that somewhat satisfies me.

> **Proposition:** Let $E$ be a Banach space and denote as $J_E:E \to E^{**}$ its inclusion in its double dual. Then given a norm one functional $\varphi \in E^*$ the following are equivalent.
>
> - $J_{E^*}(\varphi)$ is the unique functional of norm one in $E^{***}$ that extends $\varphi$ from $J_E(E)$ to $E^{**}$.
> - The identity map $(B_{E^*},w^*) \to (B_{E^*},w)$ of the unit ball of $E^*$ with the weak-$*$ topology to itself with the weak topology is continuous at $\varphi$ .

An immediate corollary is

> **Corollary:**  Let $E$ be a Banach space. The following are equivalent.
>
> - Every functional in $E$ has a unique norm-preserving extension to $E^{**}$.
> - The $w$ and $w^*$ topologies coincide in the unit ball of $E^*$.

Answer (score 3):

$C(K)$ for $K$ compact, Hausdorff, infinite satisfies the requirements. From [arXiv:math/9605213](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9605213) Remark 7, we see

> For $C(K)$ spaces, the property of being nicely smooth is equivalent to reflexivity.

Further, it is well known that for $C(K)$ spaces, $K$ finite is equivalent to reflexivity.

Finally, Remark 4 in the same paper states that

> Hahn-Banach smooth spaces are nicely smooth

where Hahn-Banach smooth spaces are exactly those for which every functional on $X$ Hahn-Banach extends uniquely to $X^{**}$. The paper however does not justify this result, though [this paper](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-18-2/18a2Band.pdf) attributes it to Godefroy:

> Godefroy, G., Nicely smooth Banach spaces, in “Texas Functional Analysis
>   Seminar 1984–1985”, (Austin, Tex.), 117 – 124, Longhorn Notes, Univ. Texas
>   Press, Austin, TX, 1985

I can't find an online version of this, nor can I prove myself that Hahn-Banach smooth spaces are nicely smooth (admittedly, I haven't tried much). Many other papers seem to cite this result however, so it seems reasonably reliable.

Comment: I'm aware of the result you mention (I believe is a theorem of Phelps).

Comment: I believe the space $C([0,1])$ satisfies the requirements, I will post more details when I'm able.

Comment: @sjvega I have updated.